# Windows 11 "save as" falls always into desktop

Tags: windows, dialog

I have an issue, whatever application I use, I always "falls" into the desktop space when I want to use the "save as" feature, that pops up the window where the user writes the filename and selects the folder.
I have to press the "back" arrow to get to the proper folder (ie, where the file is for instance).

[image: Issue]

How to avoid this annoyance ? By using a tweak in the database register ? But I cannot recall which one.
Thanks

Comment: This is not related to browser, it does this with all saveas dialog box on all application 
"Saveas" dialog box is a general windows COM object that does its own process/thread and has its own setup. 

Otherwise I'm using edge/chrome/opera

Comment: Normally applications have Save as folder settings (Browsers, all Office, Zip tools, Adobe, and so on.  Desktop is just a fall back when nothing was set